# Wondering about the need for a vapor barrier

Tags: concrete, floor, vapor-barrier

My home is on a slab.  There is a vapor barrier under the concrete.  One bedroom is about 18 inches lower than the remainder of the rooms (the original owner/builder designed it that way).  I am increasingly concerned with guests falling on the steps leading down into the room.

For that reason, I am considering raising the floor in the room.  Ceiling height is no problem.  I can raise outlets and enlarge the closet door space.  My immediate plan is to use pressure treated 2" x 6" lumber to build a grid on the existing floor (which is concrete tile).  I would overlay with foam  board and .75" plywood, then install porcelain tile to bring the floor up to the level of the rest of the house.

Do I need any sort of vapor barrier between the existing tile floor and the 2" x 6" lumber?  I live on the Gulf Coast; hardly any cold weather at all, but generally moderate humidities.

Thanks so much.

Comment: With the vapor barrier under the slab, I see no need for any additional inside under a built up floor.   I'm on the Gulf Coast too, nad did similar to what you plan.  I didn't use vapor a barrier and have had no ill effects.

Comment: @RMDman pretty sure you could make that an answer, it's the same thing I would say.

Comment: "Concrete tile"? You don't mean something like concrete pavers do you? Is that supposed to be "ceramic tile"? And this grid of 2x6s plus foam board that adds up to 18"? How does that work?

Comment: @popham -- of course, you are correct; meant to indicate ceramic tile.  

New floor will be installed above a series of braces that will rest on the existing floor. Something like this:

_____________________________
\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/     side view 
                                                  (clearly, I am not adept at commenting/formatting)

Thanks for the interest and input.  Any additional thoughts/questions will always be welcome.

Comment: @RMDman -- thanks so much.  It seemed a little unnecessary to me, but it's always helpful to hear from someone who has done something of this nature (and especially in the same climate).

Comment: I can't decipher that ASCII art, but as long as the foam board doesn't have pressure concentrations from 2x6 edges, it's probably fine. I figured 5.5"+5.5"+5.5"+foam on top or below could be your system. 2x6 edges pressing into the foam faces. There exists strong enough foam for that sort of thing, but it's relatively difficult to source.